# Chef: How to download starter kit without the web gui

Tags: chef-infra

Chef server GUI provides option to download starter kit for bootstrapping workstation without having to config CLI tools such as `knife` or `chef` by hand.

How to download this starter kit through command line without logging into the web gui on the server?

Comment: are you asking _is there a way..._ or _what is the way..._ to do so? :)

Comment: Ok : ) let me modify it to better reflect my intention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more Chef document, I came across this

> Download the entire chef-repo
>   To download the entire chef-repo from the Chef server, browse to the top level of the chef-repo and enter:
>       `$ knife download /`